# BigQuery : Regex after a string

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have a column with values *source:destination:city:street:number* and i would like to get only the city without : .

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do that?

works in both BigQuery dialects: Legacy and Standard SQL

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT('source:destination:city:street:number', r'(?:.+:){2}(.+)(?::.+){2}')
```

see more for [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract) and [re2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

> if I need the first word after source: for example?

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT('source:destination:city:street:number', r'(?:.+:){1}(.+)(?::.+){3}')
```

There are many options here for you depends on what exactly you need
Another one is below (BigQuery Legacy SQL)

```
SELECT 
  NTH(1, SPLIT(text,':')) AS source,
  NTH(2, SPLIT(text,':')) AS destination,
  NTH(3, SPLIT(text,':')) AS city,
  NTH(4, SPLIT(text,':')) AS street,
  NTH(5, SPLIT(text,':')) AS number
FROM (
  SELECT 'source:destination:city:street:number' AS text
)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, and if I need the first word after source: for example?